# Why does my Discord keep switching my status, And how can I fix it?

Tags: discord

I'm using a bot server on Discord, *Brownie RPG,* this bot uses a lot of threads to do it's gameplay, and every so often my status will go from online, to idle. This is annoying as while your on idle status you can't "read" messages. So every time I have to go change it manually. Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is it just my Discord/computer glitching?

Comment: A possible workaround I've seen is to set a custom status which you can mark to not clear. This at least should keep it from automatically going to idle.